# QML ListView sections from the code

Tags: python, qt, listview, pyqt, qml

I am unable to implement listview with sections. I've successfully repeated an example from `Qt` documentation but there is `ListModel` used which works okay, but not a `var`.

How it works with example:

```
ListView {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    id: listview
    model: ListModel {
        id: animalsModel
        ListElement { name: "Ant"; size: "Tiny" }
        ListElement { name: "Flea"; size: "Tiny" }
        ListElement { name: "Parrot"; size: "Small" }
        ListElement { name: "Guinea pig"; size: "Small" }
        ListElement { name: "Rat"; size: "Small" }
        ListElement { name: "Butterfly"; size: "Small" }
        ListElement { name: "Dog"; size: "Medium" }
        ListElement { name: "Cat"; size: "Medium" }
        ListElement { name: "Pony"; size: "Medium" }
        ListElement { name: "Koala"; size: "Medium" }
        ListElement { name: "Horse"; size: "Large" }
        ListElement { name: "Tiger"; size: "Large" }
        ListElement { name: "Giraffe"; size: "Large" }
        ListElement { name: "Elephant"; size: "Huge" }
        ListElement { name: "Whale"; size: "Huge" }
    }

    delegate: Text { text: name; font.pixelSize: 18 }

    section.property: "size"
    section.criteria: ViewSection.FullString
    section.delegate: Component {
        id: sectionHeading
        Rectangle {
            width: container.width
            height: childrenRect.height
            color: "lightsteelblue"

            Text {
                text: section
                font.bold: true
                font.pixelSize: 20
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: GUI qt example]

But when I try to use some model from the code (in my case it is a `QVariant` from `PyQt5`) it does not work at all:

```
ListView {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    id: listview
    property var m: [
        {
            name: "Animal",
            size: "Big"
        },
        {
            name: "Dog",
            size: "Small"
        },
        {
            name: "Cat",
            size: "Small"
        }
    ]
    model: m

    delegate: Text { text: modelData.name; font.pixelSize: 18 }

    section.property: "modelData.size"
    section.criteria: ViewSection.FullString
    section.delegate: Component {
        id: sectionHeading
        Rectangle {
            width: container.width
            height: childrenRect.height
            color: "lightsteelblue"

            Text {
                text: section
                font.bold: true
                font.pixelSize: 20
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I choose `var` here because there is not any other method to receive a model from Python , so any `list` or `map` from `python` needs to be wrapped as `QVariant`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Qt documentation:

**model** : *model*

`This property holds the model providing data for the list.
The model provides the set of data that is used to create the items in the view. Models can be created directly in QML using ListModel, XmlListModel or VisualItemModel, or provided by C++ model classes. If a C++ model class is used, it must be a subclass of QAbstractItemModel or a simple list.`

So you cannot provide an array as a model, it should be one of the objects above. 
You can create such model and access it from Python code to add/remove items.

```js
ListView {
    width: 100
    height: 100
    id: listview
    delegate: Text { text: name; font.pixelSize: 18 }

    model: ListModel { id: listModel }

    section.property: "size"
    section.criteria: ViewSection.FullString
    section.delegate: Component {
        id: sectionHeading
        Rectangle {
            width: container.width
            height: childrenRect.height
            color: "lightsteelblue"

            Text {
                text: section
                font.bold: true
                font.pixelSize: 20
            }
        }
    }

    function callFromPython {
        listModel.append({name: "Animal",size: "Big"});
        listModel.append({name: "Dog",size: "Small"});
        listModel.append({name: "Cat",size: "Small"});
    }
}
```

Comment: running with the same issue (using a plain array). I don't understand why  only the section don't work. According to the docs it supports a C++ simple list, why is that so much different than a javascript list...

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of issues with your code snippet:

- Bug: Use `section.property: "size"` (not `section:property: "modelData.size"`)
- Warn: Use `font.pointSize: 14` instead of (`font.pixelSize: 20`)

  - For cross-platform support, including high DPI and retina displays, best to use pointSize over pixelSize
- Warn: Replace `width: 100` and `height: 100` with `anchors.fill: parent`.

  - Avoid pixel measurements whenever we can avoid it
- Info: Use `Frame` and `ListView.view.width` for sizing delegates

  - `Frame` gives a padded border to components
- Info: Added `ScrollBar.vertical`

Here's a full working example:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model:[
            { name: "Animal", size: "Big" },
            { name: "Dog", size: "Small" },
            { name: "Cat", size: "Small" }
        ]
        delegate: Frame {
            width: ListView.view.width - 20
            Text {
                text: modelData.name
                font.pointSize: 12
            }
        }
        section.property: "size"
        section.delegate: Frame {
            width: ListView.view.width - 20
            background: Rectangle { color: "lightsteelblue" }
            Text {
                text: section
                font.bold: true
                font.pointSize: 14
            }
        }
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            width: 20
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAADYHicrVJNTwIxEL3vr2j2jI0ST3vjI55MFDFejIdSSpkw227aWRAJ/90pkmX5MHjwHTad2Ted914KZeUDiRGNatCLDI5KOfCOgseYPStrxCYTjEeI9AZmtS8TlNNzH6KcAWIhKhWMo+Zn6acGi/emTtgIp0pTiLznoFSYd0SEr1T3weZi27lMHnp7YI55Dn/nDhSdcxvqR3NibcYqYtZD4MmWqYQVTGleNJblMn12TXEjurdH3FfzSSfjCcTt4ieEoSIlk74z0oxzlpUHR+Od4rvuEeUg/HCKRhN4J6vgKxNozTaT2/yM8H8OJ0ovbPC1mxbihW9XziLfJ7RHH3g/gp1TJGNwgrVp5301n73Yy8FMPPJGCvUfgru/GtxY84vGvgpyybmBVvxkm97ldE5yqDyCXremZA9Xah2f3Mm6bbb9BloM4mE=)